# Windows server 2008r2 not executing PHP in sub-folders

Tags: windows-server-2008, php, web-hosting

I run windows server 2008r2 for purpose of web-hosting. I have plesk panel 12.0 installed on server. I created hosting for one website hardworkerz.net and default physical path is C:\inetpub\vhosts\hardworkerz.net\httpdocs directory.

I am able to execute index.php file under httdocs folder without any issues,

but when i create a subfolder by name vikas and keep index.php file in it then physical path for this folder becomes C:\Inetpub\vhosts\hardworkerz.net\httpdocs\vikas. When i browse hardworkerz.net/vikas on web i am getting error HTTP Error 403.14 I am not able to execute index.php file under sub-folder vikas.

ERROR ON SERVER:

```
 HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
 The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

 Detailed Error InformationModule   DirectoryListingModule
 Notification   ExecuteRequestHandler
 Handler    StaticFile
 Error Code 0x00000000
 Requested URL  http://www.hardworkerz.net:80/vikas/
 Physical Path  C:\Inetpub\vhosts\hardworkerz.net\httpdocs\vikas\
 Logon Method   Anonymous
 Logon User Anonymous
```

[image]

I have googled a lot but most of posts were pointing to enable directory browsing but it did not sorted out the issue. Please suggest something if anyone can help me out on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create the virtual directory of sub-folder from Plesk Panel. Once you create the virtual directory of subfolder, set the default document as "index.php". Check out following tutorial for more information.

http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP12/12.0/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-administrator-guide/index.htm?fileName=65214.htm